# How do I select properties from different classes and assigning it a value

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have two classes with different properties in each class. If the properties in myClass1 is set to null, how can I match them with the properties in myClass2 and set those to null as well? I tried using reflection but can't seem to get it to work. The issue with the way I have below is that when looping through the properties, the properties do not match to the right one from the other class.  I have snippet of my code below.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfFamilyMembers { get; set; }
    public int Birthdate { get; set; }
}


public class MyClass2
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName {get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string BirthLocation { get; set; }
}

public Overwrite(MyClass1 myclass1, MyClass2, myclass2)
{
    var props1 = from prop in typeof(myClass1).GetProperties()
                where prop.PropertyType == type(string)
                select prop;

    var props2 = from prop in typeof(myClass2).GetProperties()
                where prop.PropertyType == type(string)
                select prop;

    foreach (var property1 in props1)
    {
        foreach (var property2 in props2)
        {
            if(property1.GetValue(myClass1, null) == null)
            {
               property2.SetValue(this, string.Empty, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to set values inside a non-static class (`myClass1` and `myClass2`), you need an _instance_ of that class.

Comment: Are you comparing two lists of these objects? Comparing them one at a time?

Comment: I'm trying to compare the two list and find the properties that match. If they do match, I want to set the value of the property in myClass2 to the value of property in myClas1, which is going to be null.

Comment: Where did you define and assign `prop` and `prop2` in your code? Your code won't compile.

Comment: Just edited it. Sorry forgot I made some changes before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is like this:

```
static void Overwrite(MyClass1 o1, MyClass2 o2)
{
    o2.FirstName = o1.FirstName;
    o2.LastName = o1.LastName;
    o2.Birthdate = o1.Birthdate;
}
```

I have not seen any case made for using Reflection in this scenario.

If you insist on doing it with Reflection (not recommended), this ought to do it:

```
static void OverwriteWithReflection(MyClass1 o1, MyClass2 o2)
{
    var targetType = o2.GetType();

    foreach (var fromProperty in o1.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (!fromProperty.CanRead) continue; //Source property is write-only
        var toProperty = targetType.GetProperty(fromProperty.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (toProperty == null) continue; //No matching property
        if (!toProperty.CanWrite) continue; //Target is read only
        if (toProperty.PropertyType != fromProperty.PropertyType) continue; //Properties aren't the same type
        toProperty.SetValue(o2, fromProperty.GetValue(o1, null));
    }
}
```

[Click here to see working code example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZPQrI)